# Why other columns also not accepting alphabet in datagridview cell format?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell-formatting

I have a datagridview with 8 columns and I want the index 5 and 6 to accept numbers only, but unfortunately it also affects the other columns. is there something wrong with this code?

```
Private Sub GridJournal_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles GridJournal.EditingControlShowing
    If GridJournal.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 5 Then

        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress

    ElseIf GridJournal.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 6 Then

        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = "." Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When the Edit Controls are created, if the next one needed (for the next cell) is of the same type, the Edit Control is re-used. As the control is re-used, it will have the same KeyPress event handler attached.

Comment: You'ld also realize at some point that you have a host of event handlers hanging around. Remove the good ol' handler before adding a new one. Or use the `e.Controls` reference to handle the TextBox control using your own class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need an else condition to remove your handler.

```
   If GridJournal.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 5 Or GridJournal.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 6 Then
        RemoveHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress
        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress
    Else
        RemoveHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress
    End If
```